# chat application using socket.io in node js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Socket.io with Express. In my project I have a login page,register page and some more 
    pages  and a home page. When I do successful login, I navigate to localhost:8000/chatter where I get 
    this error:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NANyVHH 404 59.151 ms - 1908
```

I did not do any modification in my app.js (project created by express ).

app.js just created a server on localhost 8000 and using this code in another file named socketFile.js

```
var socket = io();
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
      handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
      btn = document.getElementById('send'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
    message.value = "";
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
})

// Listen for events
socket.once('connect', socketConn => {
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
});
```

I have created server in app.js ass follow

```
const PORT =process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log('Server started on port : ' + PORT))
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});
```

[Facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Qnt.png)

Comment: Where is your `createServer` instance? You have to link `io` to it

Comment: Hey man if you are looking for an example i have a private chat app here on https://github.com/halilcakar/private-chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

Comment: Here is my app.js file where I define port

Comment: var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
const PORT =process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log('Server started on port : ' + PORT))
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
module.exports = app;

Comment: I could not able to post whole code due to allowed characters limitation

Comment: You should update your question with the code, it's impossible to understand it from the comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', { title: "homechat" })
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    var m = 0
    m++;

    console.log('user join in the chat app')
    socket.on('chat message', msg => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    // console.log(total )
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        m--;
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
console.log(`total ${m} are connected`)
});


server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("this is runing on the :-3000")
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    <%=title%>
  </title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 3rem;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #form {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      padding: 0.25rem;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
      height: 3rem;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }

    #input {
      border: none;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      flex-grow: 1;
      border-radius: 2rem;
      margin: 0.25rem;
    }

    #input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    #form>button {
      
      background: #333;
      border: none;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      margin: 0.25rem;
      border-radius: 3px;
      outline: none;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #messages>li {
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }

    #messages>li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #efefef;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <form id="form" action="">
    <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
  </form>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>
    var socket = io();
    var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (input.value) {

        socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
        input.value = '';
      }
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.textContent = msg;
      messages.appendChild(item);
      // window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, and welcome. When answering an old question please explain in your answer how your answer is an improvement on the existing answers